# How to insert two records into database currently inserting only one - using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, object, authentication

This is my body request:

```
{
    "license_history": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "medical_license":"01478" ,
            "medical_license_expiration_date": "2019-01-01",
            "state_issuing_medical_license": "Punjab",
            "degree_listed_on_license": "BS",
            "medical_license_issue_date": "2019-01-01"
        },
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "medical_license":"852" ,
            "medical_license_expiration_date": "2019-01-01",
            "state_issuing_medical_license": "Punjab",
            "degree_listed_on_license": "BS",
            "medical_license_issue_date": "2019-01-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Its inserting only the one record into database which is second one i want to insert both of record:

My Controller:

```
if ($request->has('license_history')) {
    $licenseHistory = $body['license_history'];
    foreach ($licenseHistory as $history) {
        $medicalLicense = [
            'user_id' => $history['user_id'],
            'medical_license' => $history['medical_license'],
            'medical_license_expiration_date' => $history['medical_license'],
            'state_issuing_medical_license' => $history['medical_license'],
            'degree_listed_on_license' => $history['medical_license'],
            'medical_license_issue_date' => $history['medical_license_issue_date'],
        ];
        $medL = Medical_license::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $history['user_id']], $medicalLicense);
        $medL->fill($history)->save();
    }
}
```

This code will insert record against user_id and will update if record already exist against same user id but for now i want to add both of records of my objects:
How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you are using firstOrCreate function?

Comment: to update record against user id which is already exist

Comment: update if exist and create if not exists

Comment: both records have same ids. If you use firstOrCreate it should involve just 1 record, right?

Comment: yes right but i want to insert two records at the time of insertion

Comment: so i do not understand why you use firstOrCreate. Just add new record.

Comment: can you guide me using code how i can do that

Comment: can you please give example of output - what do you expect to have in DB, serialized fields? what type is medical_license field?

Comment: To add multiple rows in one query you should use `insert` method. Like so `DB::table('medical_license')->insert($licenseHistory);` but it doesn't do same thing as `updateOrCreate` it's just insterting rows without checking if one of them already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the first array argument to define what are the columns which are unique per record.
For me, it looks like you want user_id and medical_license to be unique. If so you have to make it like that

```
 Medical_license::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $history['user_id'], 'medical_license' => $history['medical_license']], $medicalLicense);
```

Comment: i dont want to unique i am already handling the scenario i want to insert two objects record currently it inserting juts one object record

Comment: so please explain better what you are trying to do, cause it seems this answer is correct

Comment: @syed1234 if that is your case even if you are handling it somewhere else you have to handle it here as well. Make the request as I showed you and you will have 2 records in your database.